# How to reverse two-finger scroll on Linux Budgie

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I don't seem to have any "Settings" section which covers this, and there is no similar question for this flavour.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xev` to verify that your two-finger scroll is mapped in the standard way: As the two mousebutton events that corresponds to a scroll wheel. Then use `xinput` (`man xinput` for details) to identify your device, and see if you can change the button mapping so these two buttons are swapped. If that doesn't work, maybe there are other properties you can change to make it work.

Finally, figure out which X driver your device uses (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`), lookup how the configuration for this driver works (e.g. `man evdev`), and create your own `xorg.conf` to activate those changes on X server start.